# Is there a way to kill a docker container that hangs for "stop" and "kill"?

Tags: docker, containers, kill

I have a docker container that when I call:

```
docker container stop wcfservicesample
```

or

```
docker container kill wcfservicesample
```

It just "hangs".  (Meaning the powershell command never returns.)

**Is there some way to kill a container that is more forceful than "kill"?**

Comment: Try: `docker rm -f <container>`

Typically, docker rm is used to remove an already stopped container, but the use of the -f flag will cause it to first issue a SIGKILL. Reference: [here](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe itis too late, but What helped me under ubuntu linux was:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker && docker rm -f <<container_id>> ...
```

I dont know why it do work only on docker restart/